# Error encrypting images with WebCryptoAPI in Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, webcrypto-api

I am trying to encrypt an image in ionic 3 using the [WebCryptoAPI](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/).

I get the image from the device's camera encoded as a Base64 string. I use the base64-arraybuffer library to convert this to an ArrayBuffer.
Following that, I create a Keypair and use the public key to encrypt using the WebCryptoAPI.

The code falls over in the last part when using crypto.encrypt(). I am getting the following error:

> {"code":34,"name":"OperationError","message":"The operation failed for
>   an operation-specific
>   reason","__zone_symbol__currentTask":{"type":"microTask","state":"notScheduled","source":"Promise.then","zone":"angular","cancelFn":null,"runCount":0}}

The Crypto implementation seems only available through interfaces, making it difficult to pin down this (to me) very generic exception - at one stage I suspected a 'zone' error - and tried to wrap the code in ngZone.run(), but to no avail.

The code runs as follows:

```
....
import base64Arraybuffer from 'base64-arraybuffer';
declare var crypto: Crypto;
...
```

```js
testCrypto() {
    // sample gif image (base64-encoded)
    const base64Image: string = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhPQ ... 0pCZbEhAAOw==";
    // convert base64 string to ArrayBuffer
    var encodedData_ab: ArrayBuffer = base64Arraybuffer.decode(base64Image);
    console.log("... arraybuffer bytelength: " + encodedData_ab.byteLength);
    // create keypair
    crypto.subtle.generateKey({
        name: "RSA-OAEP",
        modulusLength: 2048, //can be 1024, 2048, or 4096
        publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]),
        hash: { name: "SHA-256" }, 
    },
    true, 
    ["encrypt", "decrypt"])
    .then((keypair) => {
        console.log(keypair.publicKey);
        console.log(keypair.privateKey);
        // start encrypting data
        // ERROR occurs here >>>>
        crypto.subtle.encrypt({
            name: "RSA-OAEP"
        },
            keypair.publicKey,
            encodedData_ab
        )
        .then((buffer) => {
            console.log("... after encrypting data...")
            console.log(buffer.toString());
        });
    });
}
```

The ArrayBuffer seems to be present - it does show me a specific byte length.
The key pair objects also show in the console. 
The Crypto keypair generation and encryption code is based on [WebCrypto Examples](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples).

So the problem seems to be with the encoding process. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is WebCryptographiApi really implemented on Android/iOS WebView?

Comment: @pedrofb There are a few examples around that implement WebCrypto in ionic, such as [A closer look at the Web Cryptography API](https://golb.hplar.ch/2017/09/A-closer-look-at-the-Web-Cryptography-API.html). Though some types of WebCrypto (and there are many) may be more successful than others ..

Comment: I assumed you were going to use ionic to deploy the WebCrypto code in a mobile app. On the web, there's no problem. Your answer is correct. Also note that the image is not base64. You would need to remove `data: image/gif; base64` before decoding

Comment: Yes, I am using WebCrypto in an Ionic 3 app - the above code builds ok on my android (once I shorten the data string). And I do need to remove the header characters before I use it indeed. Thanks for your input, Pedro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - I learnt something ...

From [a Mozilla Bug Report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1235768), I learnt that RSA encryption only works for small messages:

> With RSA-OAEP the maximum message length you can encrypt is:
>   m - 2 - 2*hLen
>   With m=2048 and hLen=512 as in your example that is:
>   2048 - 2 - 2*512 = 1022 bits

When I shorten the data string `Base64Image` to 254 characters, it works...

I will get back to this when I find the correct implementation ...

---- EDIT ----

As Promised - I did manage to implement this using a **Hybrid Crypto** solution:

- Use Symmetric Crypto to generate a session key and encrypt/decrypt plaintext
- Use Asymmetric Crypto to encrypt/decrypt the Session key

A very helpful resource was Charles Engelke's [2016 workshop](https://github.com/engelke/fluent2016). There is a full implementation of Hybrid Crypto using the WebCypto in Lab 4!